# IDictionary to SelectList?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an IDictionary, now I want to use these values in a selectlist. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just set `"Value"` and `"Key"` for `dataValueField` and `dataTextField`. You can either do this in your View itself or from your action (haven't tested the code below).

```
var targets = new Dictionary<string, string>();
targets.Add("Key", "Value");

ViewData["MyList"] = new SelectList(targets, "Key", "Value");
```

Comment: @David: the declaration proposes: public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue>. Therefore, I recommend to switch key & values, and finally: new SelectList(targets, "Key", "Value");

Comment: @Bolt Thunder: Updated.

Comment: How to add a group? (not using linq)  The key/value obviously hold only two values and SelectList(targets, "key", "value", "group", null, null) allows for OptGrouping now -- can I create a dict like so: new Dictionary<String, ValsGroups>() where valsgroups contains two properties string value and string group, but how to pass that to the SelectList object?

Answer (score 2):

Well, [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary(VS.71).aspx) inherits from `IEnumerable` so you ought to be able to pass that dictionary to one of the constructors for [`SelectList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist.aspx).

Comment: You should pass the Values property instead of just the IDictionary though. If you just pass the IDictionary you will get key/value pairs instead of the values.

Comment: Please post the code you are using so that we can use that to test.

Comment: @Meta-Knight You normally need the keys as well for a select list. Unless you aren't using normalised data...