# How to Bind Dictionary collection from Model to Dropdown List in razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Plaese find my blow code , suggest how to bind the collection list in drop down menu;

Controller

```
Public ActionResult Registation()
{
RegisrationModel register=new RegisterationModel();
register.Country=GetContryCode();
view(register);
}
```

Model:

```
public class RegistrationModel{
Dictionary<int,string> Country=new Dictionary<int,string>();
public Dictionaly<int,string> GetCountryCode()
{

County.Add(1,"India");
Country.Add(2,"Us");
so on.
}

}
```

RazorView:Registation.cshtml-> can you plese suggest how to bind the Country property in Razor view?

Comment: I think this has been asked before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848525/idictionary-to-selectlist

Comment: Great for your information.